# Using goto to jump loop initialization

Tags: php

Error in Using goto  "goto' into loop or switch statement is disallowed"

```
goto b;
echo 'fggk'; 
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    b:
    echo 'dfgkjld';
    break;
}
echo 'fcgk'; die;
```

Comment: What isn't clear about that error message?

Answer (score 0):

look if you want to `echo` something when particular `condition` met then simply use `if condition`

```
<?php
$value = 2;
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
   if($i == $value){

      echo "dfgkjld";
   }
}
```

or you can use `continue` keyword to skip steps like this

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
   if($i != $value){

       continue;
   }
   echo "dfgkjld";
}
```